# Why are events and commands in MVVM so unsupported by WPF / Visual Studio?

Tags: wpf, events, mvvm, command

When creating an WPF application with the MVVM pattern, **it seems I have to gather the necessary tools myself** to even begin the most rudimentary event handling, e.g.

- AttachedBehaviors I get from [here](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/)
- DelegateCommands I get from [here](http://www.codeplex.com/wpf/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=14962)

Now I'm looking for some way to **handle the ItemSelected event in a ComboBox** and am getting suggestions of **tricks and workarounds** to do this (using a XAML trigger or have other elements bound to the selected item, etc.). Ok, I can go down this road, but it seems to be reinventing the wheel. It would be nice to just have an **ItemSelected command that I can handle in my ViewModel**.

**Am I missing some set of standard tools** or is everyone doing MVVM with WPF basically building and putting together their own collection of tools just so they can do the simplest plumbing tasks with events and commands, things that take only a couple lines in code-behind with a Click="eventHandler"?

Comment: I have to agree that WPF really misses a set of features for MVVM... It would be nice if Microsoft could provide some kind of "official" MVVM toolkit !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to Josh Smith's [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) about MVVM, it was unveiled to the world in October 2005 on [John Gossman's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/johngossman/archive/2005/10/08/478683.aspx).

From then I'd say it took another 2-3 years for WPF/MVVM to really take off and be accepted by the community, by then it was too late to retrofit WPF to support the issues with MVVM. Also I'd say that WPF created MVVM, so it seems backwards to have WPF change to support MVVM.

Finally, not everyone doing WPF uses MVVM, so the API needs to support the standard usage of events etc

So, to answer your question, yes everyone is currently putting their own set of tools together as the "official" support only provides the DelegateCommands framework at this time.

Comment: lol, I love this idea of "unveiling" a "pattern" as if its a product

Comment: It's too bad Microsoft doesn't release something for explicit MVVM like they did with ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 14):

You're right about the complexity of commands. I try to follow the M-V-VM pattern as close as possible, but I can't justify sophisticated workarounds just to handle a simple user event.

In my opinion, it's OK to handle a user event in the View if that greatly simplifies your code. If you do handle a user event in the View, your View's code-behind should immediately call a method on the ViewModel. This way, you are still keeping your logic in the ViewModel… you just have a little plumbing code (event handler) in the View. I know the M-V-VM purists think there should be no code in the View's code-behind, but sometimes it just makes more sense to allow some simple boilerplate code like an event handler. Remember, others may have to read/modify your code in the future and it is much easier to understand an event handler than a DelegateCommand.

Comment: +1 for being a pragmatic programmer. If you forward the calls from event handling methods in code behind, you've got your separation of concerns without needing fancy workarounds.

Comment: +1 Valid point - I'd prefer this approch anyday vs writing redundant code just to convert events to commands.

Comment: FWIW, codebehind is typically simpler and easier when you have a single command in a single place that just needs to execute.  Commands start looking more attractive when you need to have a CanExecute as well (while still not essential, it does help to group the logic together more than the alternative).  Where Commands really become superior is when you have the same action in multiple places (button/menu/toolbar/etc) or if you want to globally decorate additional behaviours like UI logging or user permissions.  But if your use case is simple they might not be worth it.

Answer (score 3):

Glad to hear I am not the only one that thinks the commanding implementations out there are **overkill**.  Databinding seems naturally well-supported but I have been banging my head for weeks trying to understand command bindings for things other than buttons and elements that inherit from it.

Thanks for posting this question.  I think from now on I am going to handle all events in the view layer with a redirect to the view model functions.  I think this is how they taught basic MVVM in one of Microsoft's XAMLFest 2-day course.  Good enough for me!

Answer (score 2):

Becuase MVVM was "invented" way after WPF... hence why large pieces of the MVVM puzzle are not part of the WPF framework.

Not only that but MVVM itself was declared a "pattern" before it was even proven/practised in the real world. Which is the complete opposite of what patterns are all about - they are usually spotted and documented *after* many years of successful use by lots of different people.

One guy coming up with an pattern does not a pattern make.

Comment: I couldn't agree more.  There's a rush to be on the pattern band wagon, and in the case of MVVM as part of XAML I'm not convinced.  I would need to see some serious production grade code.

Comment: Unless it's Jon Skeet, and pattern in question is that of butt-kicking.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this MVVM project template for VisualStudio.

http://blogs.msdn.com/llobo/archive/2009/05/01/download-m-v-vm-project-template-toolkit.aspx

With this template you get various DelegateCommand classes which cover different needs for ICommands, and a CommandReference class that helps with key bindings.

It's a good start...

Comment: yes, that's what I linked to above to DelegateCommands, I took that project, made some changed and added AttachedBehaviors and came up with this MVVM template http://tanguay.info/web/index.php?pg=codeExamples&id=195 that I use when I do MVVM, but it still isn't enough when I want to something as simple as e.g. handle an ItemSelected event on a Combobox. I'll keep adding to this as I get MVVM tools but it would be nice to find other attempts at collections like this which extend the MVVM VS template.